# Would Dijkstra's Algorithm go into dead end?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Say I have the following graph:

```
           e (destination)
           |
           | (1)
           |
           d
           |
           | (100)
           |
  (start)  a - - - b - - - c
             (1)      (1)
```

Would Dijkstra's algorithm run into a dead end? I think if I start from a, it will go a->b->c and went into dead end, therefore cannot reach e. Is that so?

Comment: You have two `c`s in there - that does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously not. From the [wikipedia description of Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm):

> .3. For the current node, consider all of its unvisited neighbors and calculate their tentative distances.

That means that if you start at `a`, `b` and `d` are both examined (i.e. their tentative distances are calculated) because they are unvisited neighbours. Because `b` has the smaller tentative distance, you visit that one next.

For your update with the extra node `e`: You arrive at `c` as described above. But you're not stuck - there is still an unvisited node with a precalculated tentative distance, namely `d` - so you visit that one next.

Comment: why? from a, you'll decide to go b, and then c. At c, all neighbors are visited.

Comment: No. As I said, starting from `a`, you immediately examine `b` and `d`. Only after that do you decide to 'go to b'. I don't know what else to say but "read the algorithm's description again".

Comment: I think I do understand the description. Do you? if the sequence is not a->b->c, what it is?